# Postgresql plpgsql stored procedure update statement in loop

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, loops, plpgsql

I need to write a plpgsql function which executes update statement in an infinite loop:

```
create function change_type() returns void as $$
begin
  loop  
    update table a set type = 1 where date < now(); 
  end loop;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

When I call this function the update statement is not executed, although I can see that the loop is running. I ran the update statement as a single query and it works. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: 0_0  First of all, **don't use a stored procedure with an infinite loop from which you don't break!**

Comment: What should I do then? I need something that will run indefinitely and depending on time make updates.

Comment: You **completely rethink what you're doing**.  Utterly and completely.

Comment: Why do you think you need this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *guess* what you are looking for is a **cronjob** to schedule a task at certain times (repeatedly). Try `man crontab` on a on UNIX / LINUX system. Preferably as system user **postgres**.

To run a query every 5 minutes, enter a line like this in your cron table. I use `crontab -e` under LINUX to edit my cron jobs:

```
* 5 * * * psql mydb -c 'UPDATE TABLE a SET type = 1 WHERE date < now()'
```

If you have more complex jobs, create a shell script with multiple SQL commands and call it like:

```
* 5 * * * psql mydb -f '/path/to/my_script.sh'
```

Or create a plpgsql function and call it:

```
* 5 * * * psql mydb -c 'SELECT myfunc()'
```

Set your system up so that the superuser postgres can log in without password (is default).

---

Or have a look at [**pgAgent**](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pgagent.html) that is shipped with [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/).

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are encountering is that a stored procedure in PostgreSQL automatically runs in its own transaction.  So the updates *are* taking place, they just aren't visible until they are committed--which happens when the stored procedure exits (which it never does in this case).

The practical effect this will have is that your server will eventually run out of disk space or memory, or both (or some other built-in safety limit), once the active transaction becomes too big.

The solution is, as @JackManey suggested, to completely rethink your strategy.  If you can explain what you're trying to accomplish, I'll bet my next pay check, there's a better way to accomplish it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've got a web application which I am developing using JSF 2.1, EJB and Primefaces. I need some function or service which runs automatically in the database when the application is launched and queries some table A and checks the column 'date' in this table. If the date is equal or less than the current date then change the values in column 'type' to some other values of the corresponding rows in table A.

Comment: I need this function to be launched once and run during the life of the application since new records will be added to the table A and need to be checked as well. I can do the same task using java Timer which periodically sends queries to the database, but I don't want to do this task in the application layer since it seems to be to costly. I thought that it can be done in the database layer and will be more effective in terms of performance. Do you have any suggestions how I can solve this problem?

Comment: @Nurzhan - "I need some function or service which runs automatically in the database when the application is launched..."  No.  No you don't.  You need a daemon or cron job that performs a single set of updates at a time.  Rethink your entire approach to what you're doing.

Comment: @Nurzhan: You haven't described the problem clearly enough to be *sure*, but it sounds like you might want a few *trigger* functions. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/trigger-definition.html

Comment: @Nurzhan: I don't know why you need a column to be updated whenever it's 'date' is older than NOW(); why not adjust your queries to compensate for this?  `SELECT *,date <= NOW() AS type ...` or `SELECT * ... WHERE date <= NOW()` should probably do it.  If you _really_ do need a periodic update, use a cron job as JackManey suggested.